# Ubuntu hangs during reboot/shutdown

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, shutdown

How'zit from South Africa.

I have a dual boot setup for Windows 10/Ubuntu 16 LTS running off of my SSD and a secondary storage 1GB HDD. Windows OS is on the SSD. Ubuntu is on a partition on the 1GB HDD, and Windows 10 uses the rest of the 1GB space of the HDD for storing documents, games, etc. Both OS's were fine until I started experiencing an issue a month or two ago.

**PROBLEM:**
After selecting the restart/shutdown option in Ubuntu everything goes normal and I get shown the Ubuntu shutdown screen with the white dots beneath the Ubuntu logo. Normally this screen would be followed by a successful reboot/poweroff (I think) but in my case **something causes my shutdown process to hang**.

I pressed the down arrow key on my keyboard whilst on the shutdown screen and I was shown a bunch of `[ OK ] Stopped something` messages as the machine proceeds.

The last two messages before it begins to hang:

```
[ ok ] Stopped Network Manager Wait Online
[ ok ] Stopped Thermal Daemon Service
```

Then it hangs for a bit, and I get these messages:

```
[ Time ] Timed out stopping /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-0
[ Time ] Timed out stopping /dev/disk/by-id/...
[ Time ] Timed out stopping /dev/disk/by-uuid/...
[ Time ] Timed out stopping /dev/disk/by-id/...
[ Time ] Timed out stopping /dev/dm-0
```

The computer does not recover or do anything else. It just does nothing. The **only thing I can do (which I hate doing) is to hold down the power button** (on my expensive gaming/developing rig). Powering off like that honestly makes me cry like a baby inside because I have heard that this is really bad for your computer hardware, and that you can corrupt your files/OS.

**SOME INFO:**
I cannot login with TTY when this problem occurs.

I tried an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` followed by a shutdown/reboot and  sometimes nothing will go wrong and the problem seems to be fixed. But, after doing the update and upgrade, If I restart again and then try to power down again the same thing happens.

I have a corsair h100i V2 CPU cooler and I know they do not have any Linux support. But the thing still works and people just use it anyway.  I am wondering if this is not causing the Thermal Daemon service to bug out. BUT it gives an `[ ok ]` message.

I also installed and started using VirtualBox around the same time this started to happen. Could it be related? Those `[ Time ]` messages seem to deal with a storage device.

Student_23 appreciates your help. Let me know if you need a system log or something, and please I do not want to do a reinstall for Ubuntu that would be a very last resort. Cheers!